# Calculator, Percentage button

Tags: swift

I tried this bit of code and linked it to the function and tag number 17. Nothing seems to happen when I hit the = sign on the calculator. Any ideas ? Or is my code incorrect? If any one ideas please attach the code to mine so I can use and learn from it. Percentage button has the tag number 0f 17.

```
@IBAction func buttons(_ sender: UIButton)
{
    if label.text != "" && sender.tag != 11 && sender.tag != 16
    {
        previousNumber = Double(label.text!)!

        if sender.tag == 12 //Divide
        {
            label.text = "/"
        }
        else if sender.tag == 13//Multiply
        {
            label.text = "x"
        }
        else if sender.tag == 14 //Minus
        {
            label.text = "-"
        }
        else if sender.tag == 15 //Plus
        {
            label.text = "+"
        }
        operation = sender.tag
        preformingMath = true
    }
    else if sender.tag == 16
    {
        if operation == 12
        {
            label.text = String(previousNumber / numberOnScreen)
        }
        else if operation == 13
        {
            label.text = String(previousNumber * numberOnScreen)
        }
        else if operation == 14
        {
            label.text = String(previousNumber - numberOnScreen)
        }
        else if operation == 15
        {
          label.text = String(previousNumber + numberOnScreen)
        }
    }
    else if sender.tag == 11
    {
        label.text = ""
        previousNumber = 0
        numberOnScreen = 0
        operation = 0
    }

    else if sender.tag == 17
    {
        if operation == 12
        {
            label.text = String(previousNumber / (previousNumber * (numberOnScreen / 100)))
        }
        else if operation == 13
        {
            label.text = String(previousNumber * (previousNumber * (numberOnScreen / 100)))
        }
        else if operation == 14
        {
            label.text = String(previousNumber - (previousNumber * (numberOnScreen / 100)))
        }
        else if operation == 15
        {
            label.text = String(previousNumber + (previousNumber * (numberOnScreen / 100)))
```

Comment: What is the "tag" number for the = sign? And it would be better to assign IBOutlets to those buttons and compare `sender` with those IBOutlet-ed properties. Also, `switch` statements seems like a better choice semantically.

Comment: What do you want to happen when `%` is pressed?  Does the display change?  What is the result of `5` `+` `10` `%` `=`?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your first problem is that this `if` should be excluding `17` also:

```
if label.text != "" && sender.tag != 11 && sender.tag != 16 {
```

Because you don't exclude `17` here, your `%` is entering that block which is meant to process the 4 math operators.

Replace that line with:

```
if label.text != "" && 12...15 ~= sender.tag {
```

Only `12` through `15` will match and enter that block.

---

I believe your `%` button should just compute the percent but not handle the pending math operation:

```
else if sender.tag == 17
{
    numberOnScreen = previousNumber * numberOnScreen / 100

    label.text = String(numberOnScreen)
}
```

That way, when you press `5 + 5 %` the screen will show `0.25` and then `=` will complete the operation giving `5.25`.

---

If you want `5` `%` to show `0.05` when you're not in the middle of an operation, implement it like this:

```
else if sender.tag == 17
{
    if operation == 0 {
        numberOnScreen /= 100
    }
    else {
        numberOnScreen = previousNumber * numberOnScreen / 100
    }
    label.text = String(numberOnScreen)
}
```

---

`+/-` code:

```
else if sender.tag == 18 {
    if preformingMath || label.text == "" {
        // do nothing to avoid crash
    }
    else if label.text?.first != "-" {
        label.text! = "-" + label.text!
    }
    else {
        label.text! = String(label.text!.dropFirst())
    }
    numberOnScreen = Double(label.text!) ?? 0
}
```

Comment: I suggest adding some diagnostic `print` statements to your code so that you can trace what is happening.  If you add `print("processing math button")`, print("processing =")`, print("processing %") to the appropriate places, your error would be more evident when you try it out in the simulator.

Comment: BTW, if want just `5` `%` to show `0.05` when you're not in the middle of an operation, do `if operation == 0 {
                numberOnScreen /= 100
            } else {
                numberOnScreen = previousNumber * numberOnScreen / 100
            }
            
            label.text = String(numberOnScreen)`

Comment: were should I place this bit of code ? in the buttons function ?

Comment: That code goes inside `else if sender.tag == 17 { }`

Comment: Thanks again helping me learn more than you realise! Would you have any ideas on coding the +/- button ?

Comment: `if label.text.first != "-" { label.text! = "-" + label.text! } else { label.text! = String(label.text!.dropFirst() }` then compute `numberOnScreen`.  You'll have to decide what to do if they press `-` when the screen is blank.  Doing nothing is one option.

Comment: The other way to do it would be `numberOnScreen = -numberOnScreen` and then update the label.

Comment: can you update the code as you did before, I'm going away for a hour so ill have a look over it when I'm back. Thanks again

Comment: Works great, last problem is the '( )' button, could you do the same please above. Thanks

Comment: I’m an RPN guy. I’m not even sure what `()` is even supposed to do. You’ll first need a very clear idea of how that works. If you post a clear description of what `()` does, the code you’ve tried to solve it, what your code does, and the expected results someone might be able to help you.